# Kill the docker container if the JVM processes running inside dies

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, jvm

I am new to Docker, and I was trying out a particular scenario for which I do not find any solution online or on forums.

The detail on my setup is such that, I am using Docker 17.12 on Linux with a compose setup. I have a container that contains a Java process. As a program functionality, we shut down the running Java program based on a few conditions, so as to avoid further damage to the data and consistency of our program. Once detected that the Java program has gone down, we manually bring it up by doing docker stack deploy.

Is there any functionality/signal/setting available in Docker which will kill the container (self-destroy or self-rm) once it detects that the Java program running within it has shut down?

Comment: That's how it normally works: if the main process inside the container exits, the container exits too.  Do you have a particular setup where it's working differently?

Comment: It look like you are not starting the JVM process using CMD command of Docker... We do that for some scenarios where we need to do soem pre work before launching java process... i.e We start bash script which in turn launch java as sub process... If you follow similar approach, then we use trap function of bash to find kill signal form container and notify JVM.. similarly we keep a while loop that check jvm pid activeness and exit bash to let container shutdown...

Answer (score 1):

If properly set up, **the container is the JVM process**. Keep in mind that containers are nothing but processes that have been contained in terms of resource usage as well as isolated in terms of filesystem and Linux namespaces.

So, make sure you start the container **by running Java in your entrypoint and/or command configuration**, rather than using a process manager like *systemd* as might be the case in your setup.

This usually looks something like this in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:14   
COPY /build/libs/your-application.jar ./ 
CMD java -jar your-application.jar
```